# jQuery Multivalue Pop-up prompt

Tags: jquery, html, prompt

I have some jquery code that is doing an ajax lookup and returning comma delimited values (value1, value2, value3...)

I want to prompt the user with these values to find out which one they want.

I'm not having much luck finding an jquery extension that will give me a pop-up window, show list of values and return the seleted value.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a JQuery UI library with a Dialog class.  You will have to put the values on the form, but it does the modal part with no problem.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Comment: Thank you.  That points me in the right direction.  I should be able to create a modal form with the listbox field.